# Oracle: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA

Tags: excel, oracle, tnsnames

I'm trying to connect an Oracle DB with an Excel worksheet 2013 but when I try the connection through the Power Query this message comes up " Oracle: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA "
I've downloaded the client package from the official website
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html
and installed it 64-bit ODAC 12c Release 4 (12.1.0.2.4) for Windows x64, but still, it doesn't work.

I've also put into the folder `C:\app\client\user\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin         the following files : sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora`

The second one I modified in this way:

```
<data source alias> =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ******amazonaws.com)(PORT = 1521)
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ****the name of SID****)
    )
  )
```

What should I do more?

There are a lot of topic regarding this error and I've tried everything. Could you please help me?

Comment: Did you set up an ODBC connection and test it?